# Tempo de processamento de funções

Tags: r, runtime

Como verifico o tempo de processamento das subfunções de uma função, a fim de otimizá-la?

Li sobre o tema no help do R e em: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~nolan/stat133/Fall05/lectures/profilingEx.html

Mas ele não mostra as subfunções da minha função, no entanto mostra muitas funções que nem estou usando (Não que eu saiba). É possível fazer gráficos dos desempenhos também?

Um exemplo:

```
exemplo = function(x){
  res= 0
  for(i in 1 : length(x)){
    res = res + x[i]
  }
  print(res)
  res_raiz = sqrt(abs(res))
  return(res/res_raiz)
}
teste = rnorm(10000)
exemplo(teste)
```

Comment: Você pode colocar um exemplo de uma função que quer avaliar? O método mais "tosco" é simplesmente salvar o `Sys.time()` antes e depois, mas como você já viu existem soluções mais robustas.

Comment: Wagner, agradeço que você tenha marcado minha resposta como correta, mas sugiro que você mude para a do Carlos. O pacote que citei não está mais em desenvolvimento e esta resposta pode se tornar inválida a qualquer momento, a resposta do Carlos é mais condizente com a melhor abordagem atualmente.

Comment: Eita, eu errei. Agradeço a vocês pelas inúmeras ajudas e sinceridade. Estão salvando meu mestrado, hehehe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu exemplo de teste é muito rápido, com isso os profiling vão ter dificuldade de motrar muita coisa. Vamos gerar um vetor de teste maior para fazer demorar mais o teste:

```
teste = rnorm(10000000)
```

O profiling básico do R pode ser feito com a função `Rprof()`.

```
Rprof()
exemplo(teste)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()
$by.self
          self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"exemplo"      4.48    96.55       4.64    100.00
"+"            0.16     3.45       0.16      3.45

$by.total
          total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"exemplo"       4.64    100.00      4.48    96.55
"+"             0.16      3.45      0.16     3.45

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 4.64
```

Com esse tamanho de teste o `Rprof()` já o mostra o `+`, que é onde você gasta boa parte do tempo (por causa do loop).

Um pacote útil para profiling é o [`profvis`](https://github.com/rstudio/profvis), que também usa o `Rprof()` mas torna a visualização mais fácil. Para instalar use `devtools::install_github("rstudio/profvis")`. No seu caso você faria:

```
library(profvis)
p <- profvis({exemplo(teste)})
p
```

E aí aparece a mesma informação do `Rprof()` só que de uma maneira visual. A nova versão do RStudio já virá com isso integrado.

Comment: Cinelli, o R diz que este pacote, `profvis`, não existe. `package ‘profvis’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)`

Comment: @WagnerJorge o `profvis` ainda está somente no github, para instalar: `devtools::install_github("rstudio/profvis")`

Comment: Eu intalei o `devtools` e o usei o comando, mas deu o seguinte erro: 

`* installing *source* package 'profvis' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'digest'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'profvis'
* removing 'C:/Users/Wagner/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/profvis' `

Comment: @WagnerJorge você tem que instalar o pacote `digest` manualmente também, porque não está listado como dependência. É só rodar `install.packages("digest")`.

Answer (score 3):

Uma boa opção pra você é o pacote `lineprof` do Hadley Wickham. Como o pacote não está no CRAN, você tem que instalar a partir do GitHub utilizando o pacote `devtools`:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("hadley/lineprof")
library(lineprof)
```

Essa instalação pode demorar um pouco, especialmente se for necessário o download do RTools (que é um conjunto de programas necessários para instalar um pacote do código fonte, instalado fora do R).

O `lineprof` faz o profiling linha a linha do código. Para utilizá-lo, sua função **deve** estar em um arquivo .R separado, e ser carregada utilizando `source()`:

Arquivo exemplo.R (modifiquei seu exemplo para ter um output mais útil, a função não funciona bem com `for` e também não vai ter resultado para operações muito rápidas):

```
exemplo = function(x){
  res= 0
  sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
    res <- i + res
    })
  res_raiz = replicate(1000, sqrt(abs(res)))
  return(res/res_raiz)
}
```

Finalmente, pra fazer o profiling, você pode ir em outro arquivo ou no console:

```
source("exemplo.R")
lp <- lineprof(exemplo(rnorm(1e5)))
lp
# time  alloc release dups                           ref
# 1 20.599 64.278  35.223    2         c("sapply", "lapply")
# 2  0.002  0.001   0.000    0                      "sapply"
# 3  1.050  0.320   0.000    1 c("sapply", "simplify2array")
# 4  0.001  0.002   0.000    0                  character(0)
# 5  0.192  0.656   0.000    2      c("replicate", "sapply")
# 6  0.001  0.001   0.000    0                           "/"
# 7  0.012  0.001   0.000    0                  character(0)
```

Além dessa visualização simples, você pode também navegar nos resultados utilizando o pacote `shiny`:

```
shine(lp)
```

Nessa visualização você pode navegar nos níveis das funções pra ver internamente o que é mais lento.

Você pode ver mais detalhes sobre proofing e do uso desta função no [site do Hadley](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html#measure-perf).

Comment: O lineprof foi deprecado, o pacote que o substituiu é o profvis.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Realmente, nem me atentei pra isso... Minha resposta não tem tanto sentido então, mas vou deixar já que já está escrita.